# Spring Integration Idempotent Receiver & Zookeeper Metadata Store

Tags: spring-integration

I have added Zookeeper Metadata store with filter in my batch job code to sync data in cluster environment and scale horizontally on multiple JVM. But all my messages are going in discard channel and getting below error in logs one time when job (Jpa adapter) run.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        componenti0_.id as id1_4_,
        componenti0_.component_info_file_id as componen2_4_,
        componenti0_.component_serial_no as componen3_4_,
        componenti0_.date_received as date_rec4_4_,
        componenti0_.date_recorded as date_rec5_4_,
        componenti0_.engine_hours as engine_h6_4_,
        componenti0_.is_processed as is_proce7_4_,
        componenti0_.product_serial_no as product_8_4_ 
    from
        cs_component_info componenti0_
2017-03-15 21:28:55.290  INFO [componentdatafiles,,,]       39712 --- [54.26.101:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          :  Session establishment complete on server **************, sessionid = 0x35a82a934c40127, negotiated timeout = 40000
2017-03-15 21:28:55.294  INFO [componentdatafiles,,,]       39712 --- [54.26.100:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          :  Session establishment complete on server *************, sessionid = 0x25a82aab90a0122, negotiated timeout = 40000
2017-03-15 21:28:55.313  INFO [componentdatafiles,,,]       39712 --- [p-1-EventThread] o.a.c.f.state.ConnectionStateManager     :  State change: CONNECTED
2017-03-15 21:28:55.313  INFO [componentdatafiles,,,]       39712 --- [p-1-EventThread] o.a.c.f.state.ConnectionStateManager     :  State change: CONNECTED
2017-03-15 21:28:55.332  INFO [componentdatafiles,,,]       39712 --- [54.26.101:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          :  Session establishment complete on server ****************, sessionid = 0x35a82a934c40128, negotiated timeout = 40000
2017-03-15 21:28:55.333  INFO [componentdatafiles,,,]       39712 --- [p-1-EventThread] o.a.c.f.state.ConnectionStateManager     :  State change: CONNECTED
2017-03-15 21:28:55.507  INFO [componentdatafiles,053728794a9688b3,374707c3669809db,false]       39712 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   :  [com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@4f31c4d6, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@54405aa7, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@584f0396, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@25710ebd, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@3b490019, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@6d0ae0b5, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@4df90d31, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@6050f6d5, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@13ea7b0e, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@29df2e8e, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@2c4a2e01, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@4b4b8303, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@bb9b36f, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@5b4257c8, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@77a57353, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@3e909678, com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@53e4f875]
2017-03-15 21:28:55.511  INFO [componentdatafiles,053728794a9688b3,83a7350bbbdb4b79,false]       39712 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   :  com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@4f31c4d6
2017-03-15 21:28:55.519  INFO [componentdatafiles,9f9c46137110bacc,a02fd11fe137a83c,false]       39712 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   :  org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: @componentInfoMetadataStore.get(payload.id) == null; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=com.deere.componentdatafiles.domain.ComponentInfo@4f31c4d6, headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceSize=17, X-Message-Sent=true, messageSent=true, spanTraceId=053728794a9688b3, spanId=91816fafd9b447d0, X-B3-SpanId=91816fafd9b447d0, currentSpan=[Trace: 053728794a9688b3, Span: 91816fafd9b447d0, Parent: 053728794a9688b3, exportable:false], X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=053728794a9688b3, correlationId=3bac32df-115c-4ff1-8270-2bfca59a4e83, id=4ad7414c-7b63-cfa8-fb03-ce2e20bf16b8, X-Current-Span=[Trace: 053728794a9688b3, Span: 91816fafd9b447d0, Parent: 053728794a9688b3, exportable:false], spanSampled=0}]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:143)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.filter.AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.accept(AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter.doHandleRequestMessage(MessageFilter.java:161)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingPostProcessingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingPostProcessingMessageHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:159)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:210)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.zookeeper.metadata.ZookeeperMetadataStore.get(ZookeeperMetadataStore.java:205)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpEQ.getValueInternal(OpEQ.java:42)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpEQ.getValueInternal(OpEQ.java:32)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:128)
    ... 49 more
```

I wonder if I am missing some configuration details when setting up the Metadatastore or use of expression is improper.
Below is my configuration detail.

```
    <int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
        channel="inboundChannelAdapterOne" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
        auto-startup="true" jpa-query="select cmpntinfo from ComponentInfo cmpntinfo"
        expect-single-result="false" delete-after-poll="false">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="${componentInfoPollarInterval}">
            <!-- <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> -->
        </int:poller>
    </int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <splitter id="splitter" input-channel="inboundChannelAdapterOne"
        output-channel="splitteroutputChannel" />


    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="idempotentServiceChannel"/>

      <integration:channel id="discardChannel" />

    <int:filter input-channel="splitteroutputChannel"
            output-channel="idempotentServiceChannel"
            discard-channel="discardChannel"
            expression="@componentInfoMetadataStore.get(payload.id) == null"/>


    <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="idempotentServiceChannel"
                              expression="@componentInfoMetadataStore.put(payload.id, 'payload.componentSerialNo')"/>

   <int:service-activator id="componentInfoPollarActivator"
        input-channel="idempotentServiceChannel" ref="componentInfoPollarConsumer"
        method="componentInfoListen" /> 

      <int:service-activator id="discardChannelActivator"
        input-channel="discardChannel" ref="componentInfoPollarConsumer"
        method="discard" /> 

    <beans:bean id="componentInfoMetadataStore"
        class="org.springframework.integration.zookeeper.metadata.ZookeeperMetadataStore">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="componentInfoZookeeperClient" />
        <beans:property name="root" value="/componentInfoMetaDataStore" />
        <beans:property name="phase" value="-2147483648" />
    </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="componentInfoZookeeperClient"
        class="org.springframework.integration.zookeeper.config.CuratorFrameworkFactoryBean">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="${zookeeper.server.uri}" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error implies the metadata store is not started yet.

It needs to be started before the adapter.

Try setting its `phase` property to a big negative number - like `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (so it's started early).

Comment: After setting phase property to Integer.MIN_VALUE value error logs is not coming but still all messages are going to discard channel.Is it key-value is not clearing from Metadata store ? Edited configuration in questiion

Comment: value in metadata store is not clearing componentInfoMetadataStore.put(payload.id, payload.componentSerialNo)

Comment: Where are you clearing it? I only see `get` and `put`. So it seems to be working as expected - once the key is in the store subsequent messages with the same key are discarded.

Comment: Actually I am testing on limited amount of similar data that why message going in discard channel, Not clearing key value from metadat store explicitly. I got confuse with this line in your post of github  "The value of the idempotent entry may be some expiration date, after which that entry should be removed from Metadata Store by some scheduled reaper."